# What does converter="theme" refer to in the p:pickList example?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

The [Primefaces pickList examples](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml) contains the declaration

```
<p:pickList id="PojoPickList" value="#{pickListView.themes}" var="theme" effect="bounce"
            itemValue="#{theme}" itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true" responsive="true"
            showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
            converter="theme">
```

What does `converter="theme"` refer to? The only possible reference is the value of `var`, but that's not a valid converter is it? Extracting the example into a separate Java EE project and running it on GlassFish 4.1 not surprisingly causes failure ~`named object theme not found`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In showcase [ThemeConverter.java](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/convert/ThemeConverter.java) file is missing and in there you can see the real name being used and notice 'theme' is a typing error. Use below code in the sample project.

```
<p:pickList id="PojoPickList" value="#{pickListView.themes}" var="theme" effect="bounce"
                        itemValue="#{theme}" itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true"
                        showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" converter="themeConverter" responsive="true">
```

I will try to fix in github project also.